# Select Fields From Table - MYSQL JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am having table x.

```
x
............
id    email      first_name   last_name
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 1  a@gmail.com  Martin        Robert
 2  b@gmail.com     
 3  c@gmail.com  Sam           Anderson
```

I am using following query and the output is:

```
 select id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) from a;

 The output is
 .......................................
 id    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  1    Martin Robert
  2
  3    Sam Anderson
```

I Want to ignore the row which has both first_name and last_name is empty in CONCAT().

My output will be as follows

```
  .......................................
 id    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  1    Martin Robert
  3    Sam Anderson
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you need a WHERE clause in your query

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
select id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) from a where first_name is not null and last_name is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  where clause

assuming the empty value mean null value

```
 select id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 
 from a 
 where first_name is NOT null 
 and last_name is NOT null;
```

or for test also empty string

```
 select id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 
 from a 
 where ifnull(first_name,'') = '' 
 and ifnull(last_name,'') =  '';
```

Comment: Might need to add a `and first_name != ''` as that may not actually be null :)

Comment: What is the difference this this from the answer below?

Comment: @VijunavVastivch  the first just check if the value is not assigned  (NULL)  the second check if the value is not assigned  or the value in as empty string  (null or '')

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME)
FROM TABLE_NAME_A
WHERE FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND LAST_NAME IS NOT
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54804215/edit) your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should must work in your case:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as fullname 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
WHERE first_name != "" AND last_name != "";
```